# Linear layout adapting to screen size without overlap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have an Android layout of an activity shown below. The layout is divided into a header and a footer. The middle part is divided into equally weighted segments and each segment has a text above. With this layout I have two issues:

First, when the layout is displayed on a small screen the text and images are vertically overlapping. What I instead want is that the images and the text scale so that they are not overlapping on any screen size. I assume that this could be achied by moving the texts into the equally weighted parts (i.e. `@+id/row1`, `@+id/row2`, `@+id/row3`). But I don't know how this can be done and if that is real the solution.

Does somebody know what to do?

Second, the question mark in the header is too big in relation to the text. On the screenshot the text is only on one line so the question mark should be smaller. On smaller screens, the text is perhaps on two lines, then the question mark should get bigger. That means how can I achieve it so that the question mark is adapting to the height of the text?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/state_description"
            android:background="@color/eth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="This is a tile" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/sam_help_button"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/question_mark_white"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="This is the title of the first three images" />

            <!-- Row number 1 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_contour"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_contour"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_contour"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/valence_pos_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/valence_pos_image"
                            android:layout_width="65dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Positive"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/valence_neutral_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/valence_neutral_image"
                            android:layout_width="65dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Neutral"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/valence_neg_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/valence_neg_image"
                            android:layout_width="65dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Negative"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="This is the title of the second three images" />

            <!-- Row number 2 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row2"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_contour"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_contour"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_contour"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/arousal_high_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/arousal_high_image"
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="High"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/arousal_neutral_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/arousal_neutral_image"
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Medium"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/arousal_low_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/arousal_low_image"
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Low"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="This is the title of the last three images" />

            <!-- Row number 3 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row3"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_contour"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_contour"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_contour"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dominance_low_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dominance_low_image"
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Controlled"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dominance_neutral_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dominance_neutral_image"
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Neutral"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dominance_high_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dominance_high_image"
                        android:layout_width="65dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="In-control"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sam_button_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/submit_sam_button"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:background="@drawable/button"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_check_circle_white_24dp"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:text="Next" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cancel_sam_button"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:background="@drawable/button"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_cancel_white_24dp"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:text="Cancel" />
                </RelativeLayout >

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem your are facing is because of hard-coded layout sizes such as,

```
layout_height=60
layout_width=60
```

instead you must use,

```
layout_height="match_parent/wrap_content"
layout_width="match_parent/wrap_content"
```

have a look at this,

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6AVdCKoyiQ

you should also use layout_weight attribute,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swZhVj6r6x0

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm already using layout_weight attribute. When I use wrap_content for the imageView then the image gets very big (much bigger than the text height. Can you please give an example how to change my code for the two problems?